Бот не видит команды из когов
Ситуация следующая: я нашёл бота на гитхабе, но почему-то он не работает.
Частичный код:
class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('$'), intents=intents)
        self.Timer, self.endTime, self.startText = None, None, None
        self.blvPercent, self.dbtPercent, self._last_member = None, None, None
        self.predictionDB, self.betCollection = None, None
        self.dbList = []

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Bot has logged in as {bot.user}')
        addGuild()
        this = Timer(1800, voiceChannelCheck)
        this.start()
        bot.dbList = listGuild()
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self):
        addGuild()
        pass


class Predictions(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.message = None
        self.StartMessage = None
    @commands.command(aliases=['set'], description=startComDescription)
    @has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True)
    async def start(self, ctx, title, t: int, blv, dbt):
        ---реализация команды---

    ---другие команды---


bot = Bot()
bot.add_cog(Predictions(bot))
bot.run(TOKEN)

Когда я пытаюсь использовать команду, мне консоль отвечает:
discord.ext.commands.bot:Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "start" is not found
При этом если запустить отладку и посмотреть объект бота, то все команды он видит и определяет

